# Enable foreign key support for Sqlite3 in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have enabled foreign keys in SQLITE using PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; and have confirmed it's working below.

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE transactions (
   ...>     id integer primary key,
   ...>     amount REAL,
   ...>     item TEXT,
   ...>     created DATETIME,
   ...>     modified DATETIME,
   ...>     date DATE,
   ...>     time TIME,
   ...>     description TEXT,
   ...>     transaction_type_id INTEGER,
   ...>     category_id INTEGER,
   ...>     account_id INTEGER,
   ...>     location_id INTEGER,
   ...>     FOREIGN KEY (transaction_type_id) REFERENCES transaction_types(id),
   ...>     FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id),
   ...>     FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id),
   ...>     FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
   ...> );
sqlite> INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (null, '5.0', 'test', '2013-06-11 18:33:56', '2013-06-11 18:33:56', '2013-06-11', '18:33:00', 'test description', 2, 1, 2, 1);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM categories;
1|fsfs|2013-06-11 18:33:38|2013-06-11 18:33:38
sqlite> SELECT * FROM transactions JOIN categories ON transactions.category_id=categories.id;
4|5.0|test|2013-06-11 18:33:56|2013-06-11 18:33:56|2013-06-11|18:33:00|test description|2|1|2|1|1|fsfs|2013-06-11 18:33:38|2013-06-11 18:33:38
sqlite> DELETE FROM categories WHERE id=1;
Error: foreign key constraint failed
sqlite>
```

However, when I try to do this through CakePHP, I get no errors about foreign key constraints and the category is deleted. Below are my Transaction and Category models.

Transaction.php:

```
class Transaction extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Location', 'TransactionType', 'Category', 'Account');
....
```

Category.php:

```
class Category extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Transaction', 'Budget'); 
....
```

My delete function for Category in CategoriesController.php is done through a component function and they are as follows.

CategoriesController.php -> delete

```
public function delete($id) {
    $this->Crud->delete($this, $id, "Category");
}
```

CrudComponent.php -> delete

```
public function delete($current, $id, $modelName) {
    $className = strtolower(Inflector::humanize($modelName));
    if ($current->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    if ($current->$modelName->delete($id)) {
        $current->Session->setFlash('The '.$className.' with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
        $current->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

I think my associations are set up fine as I have no problems retrieving data. However, the foreign keys are not being obeyed on delete.

I suspect it's something to do with having to run "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON" every time CakePHP connects to the database but I'm not sure how to do this. Or it might be something wrong with my Model definitions and associations.

I'm using CakePHP version 2.3.5 and Sqlite3 version 3.7.13.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you :)

Comment: I solved this by changing my connect function in Sqlite.php in /lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/ by adding 

`$this->execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");`

after successful connect.

Does anyone know if this is the right way to do it? Or if there is a better way? As far as I know this has to be done each time a connection is made to the database and I couldn't see anywhere better to put it! 

Thank you :)